# How to log an exception and rethrow as the actual type

Tags: c#

I have a query handler decorator which logs any exceptions:

```
public class QueryHandlerLogDecorator<TQuery, TResult> : IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>
    where TQuery : IQuery<TResult>
{
    private readonly IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> _handler;
    private readonly ILog _log;

    public QueryHandlerLogDecorator(IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> handler)
    {
       _handler = handler;
       _log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
    }

    public TResult Handle(TQuery query)
    {
        try
        {
             var result = _handler.Handle(query);

            _log.Info("Ok");

            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _log.Error(ex.Message, ex);                

            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Whilst the exception handling isn't the worst thing in the world, what it means is that I lose the type of the exception being thrown.

For example, if I throw `ApplicationException` lower down in the application, this is caught and rethrown as `Exception`.

How can I rethrow the exception being caught as the original type?

Comment: Just "throw;" is enough...

Comment: @CodeGray: The previous duplicate was a better fit since it exactly asked the same question. This new duplicate is broader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `throw;` instead of `throw new...` or instead of `throw ex;`

> Once an exception is thrown, part of the information it carries is the
>   stack trace. The stack trace is a list of the method call hierarchy
>   that starts with the method that throws the exception and ends with
>   the method that catches the exception. If an exception is re-thrown by
>   specifying the exception in the throw statement, the stack trace is
>   restarted at the current method and the list of method calls between
>   the original method that threw the exception and the current method is
>   lost. To keep the original stack trace information with the exception,
>   use the throw statement without specifying the exception.

More here : [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182363.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Rethrow the exception by just using the `throw` keyword. This will rethrow the exception as passed to the exception handler.

```
public TResult Handle(TQuery query)
{
    try
    {
         var result = _handler.Handle(query);

        _log.Info("Ok");

        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _log.Error(ex.Message, ex);                
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that so? OK, I'll modify the answer.